# valac says undef ref but libgee exists

Tags: vala, libgee

When I try to compile a vala or genie program needing libgee,  I get undefined references to gee_array_list_new, etc.  I have libgee installed from source; its .so file is right there in plain sight in /usr/local/lib, its other files as they should be.   But when I install libgee with my distro's package manager, the vala program links fine!   I'm looking for a difference to explain this, but am stumped.  The libraries are slightly different versions, but not by much.

Does valac somehow fail to look in /usr/local/lib?  What are likely explanations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you `pkg-config --libs gee-1.0` doesn't include -L/usr/local/lib`.

Make sure you have `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` if you want valac to link with /usr/local/lib libraries.

Comment: Indeed, the pkgconfig file from my homebrew install wasn't entirely sane.  Luckily this distro's version is up to date. so all is well.